# MySQL Multiple Unique Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have an existing MySQL users table with thousands of records in it. I have noticed duplicate records for users which is a problem that I need to address. I know that the way I need to do this is to somehow make 2 columns unique.

The duplicates are arising with records containing both the same **server_id** column, and also the same **user_id** column. These 2 columns are meant to be unique combined. So there should only ever be 1 **user_id** per **server_id**.

I have figured out how I can find these duplicates using the following query:

```
SELECT `server_id`, `user_id`, COUNT(*) AS `duplicates` FROM `guild_users` GROUP BY `server_id`, `user_id` HAVING `duplicates` > 1
```

From what I have read, I need to delete all duplicates first before I add any constraints. This is one of the things I am unsure about.

**Question 1:** How would I go about deleting all duplicates, but leaving 1 of each so the user still exists, just not the other duplicates.

**Question 2:** What is the best way of avoiding duplicates from being created? Should I create a unique constraint for both of the columns, or do something with primary keys instead?

Comment: Since the problem is partly about the table schema, it'd be wise if you added the `show create table` output to the question. Hint: look into [composite keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), your primary should be one using the two columns.

Comment: i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example data and expected results.. This way we how which record you want to keep from all the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table there must exist a primary key column like an `id`.
So you can use EXISTS to delete the duplicates and keep just 1:

```
delete gu from guild_users gu
where exists (
  select 1 from guild_users
  where 
    server_id = gu.server_id 
    and 
    user_id = gu.user_id
    and
    id > gu.id
)
```

After that you can create a unique constraint for the 2 columns:

```
alter table guild_users 
add constraint un_server_user unique 
(server_id, user_id);
```

Comment: I am getting this error when running your first piece of code: Unknown column 'gu.server_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Am I meant to change something with that? I wrote it the same way as you showed, as guild_users is the name of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prevent this by adding a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_guild_users_server_user on guild_users(server_id, user_id);
```

If you have a primary key, you can delete the duplicates *before* adding the unique index:

```
delete g
    from guild_users g left join
         (select server_id, user_id, max(primary_key) as max_pk
          from guild_users
          group by server_id, user_id
         ) su
         on gu.primary_key = su.max_pk
    where su.max_pk is null;
```

Comment: yes but isn't his question about how to create a unique index on data which violates the unique constraint already so he can't made that unique key first.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I run your code for deleting the duplicates, even when changing primary_key to my id field: Unknown column 'gu.max_pk' in 'where clause'